# Recycler View only showing after I press an Edit Text

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment with a search bar (edit text) and a recycler view underneath. To display my recycler view I use an adapter. I am trying to display all the friends of a user. The problem is the recycler view items don't appear unless I tap in the search bar (without typing anything).
Furthermore, when loading the images from my database into the image views they get mixed up.
My database is as follows:

```
{
 "Friends": {
            "id3":{
                "id1": "name1",
                "id2": "name2",
                ...
            },
            "id4":{
                "id1": "name1",
                "id3": "name3",
                ...
            }, ...
 },
 "Users": {
          "id1":{
             info about user1
          },
          "id2":{
             info about user2
          },
          "id3":{
             info about user3
          },
          "id4":{
             info about user4
          }, ...
 }
}
```

I debugged a little bit and found my onCreateViewHolder never gets called when the fragment gets created (not sure if this is relevant).
I also tried to use another query which simply displays all users in the database (so just iterating through the children of the node "Users"). That did work so I imagine the problem is with my queries. However I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

How I link my recycler view to my adapter:

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_invite_recycler);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

searchBar = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_invite_search_bar);

mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
mAdapter = new EventUserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My friends query:

```
Query friends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Friends").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).orderByValue();

friends.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Query users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(snp.getKey());

                    users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            assert user != null;
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

My adapter:

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_event, viewGroup, false);

        return new EventViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventViewHolder eventViewHolder, int i) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final User user = mUsers.get(i);

        eventViewHolder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
        if (user.getImgURL() != null) Glide.with(eventViewHolder.icon.getContext()).load(user.getImgURL()).into(eventViewHolder.icon);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }
```

My ViewHolder:

```
public class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView username;
        public ImageView check;
        public CircleImageView icon;

        public EventViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final onItemClickListener listner) {
            super(itemView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_event_name);
            icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_event_image);
            check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_event_check);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand from you question whether it's working or not, and what is the problem. Could you rephrase?

Comment: Well, when I open the fragment the recycler view is empty. Then whenever I tap on the search bar (without writing anything) the recycler view gets populated. However I want all the data to appear as soon as I create the fragment (and not only after tapping the search bar).

Comment: But you said that once you've added a query that displays all users the app was working properly. From where i sit, the initial problem was that you didn't fill your `recyclerview` with content after creating its `EventUserAdapter` adapter, but only when using the `editText`. So, a query that initially displays all users solve that. What more do you need?

Comment: The above provided query is called initially before an OnTextChange from the EditText. So it should appear before I type in the search bar right?
I also noticed that the mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't updated the values inside the adapter until after I use the search bar.

Comment: If you call the query at activity's creation, (onCreate, onStart etc.) it should appear regardless of whether you typed anything in the `editText` or not. When you call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it's actually call `onBindViewHolder` for the currently displayed views. Your `onBindViewHolder` method seems fine to me, you get your data from the current view's position and update the view properly. Check if this method is even called after you do `notifyDataSetChanged` (with logs or debug). If it is called, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: That is why I am confused! Logically something would need to appear but there is nothing. I checked and my onBindViewHolder doesn't get updated with my notifyDataSetChanged method. Maybe the way I construct my query makes it so that the notifyDataSetChanged never gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the location of `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
 in *My friends query* section.
You are calling the command outside of the inner callback from `users.addValueEventListener` and this might be too early, your users array just been cleared and hasn't been populated yet.

Try to do something like:

```
friends.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mUsers.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // for the current views actually reset
        // you could also do mAdpater.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, mUsers.size()) but before clearing the list of course

        for (DataSnapshot snp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Query users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(snp.getKey());

            users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    assert user != null;
                    mUsers.add(user);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1); // to display the current user in the recyclerview
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

If still not working, maybe you're using two different lists of users, one in activity and second in the adapter? check if you are saving the original list's reference or generating new one based on the original's values (at the adpater's constructor). Then, updating the activity's list won't affect the adapter's list.

I hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Indeed it appears I called my notifyDataSetChanged in the wrong place. I also made  some improvements so that you can simply call mAdapter.add(item) which then adds directly an item to the list in the adapter which in turns call notifyDataSetChanged. Thank you very much for the help :)